# Handling a big amount of JMS message types

Tags: java, design-patterns, jms, activemq-classic

i'm new to jms, and i'm currently designing a BattleShip game.
I'm using jms with activemq for the communication between them, so far i made 4 classes for jms communication which are Topic and Queue receivers and senders with simple methods of changing destination and sending.

Now i'm facing a problem when want to handle these messages,
I've decided every message will be delivered via ObjectMessage and the inner object will tell the listener how to handle it.

I have 5 different categories for messages :
Authentication,
Data (Such as highscores, replays etc),
InGameMessages (ShipRegistration, TurnUpdate and so on),
ChatMessage,
MatchMakingMessages (Only GameSearch and GameSearchCancel),

So i thought it will be a good idea to add a MessageType enum to each message,
but eventually I ended up writing the listener with over than 20 cases at the switch statement and with a huge amount of class castings.

Now I want to write it all over again, but i'm still stuck on the message handling since I can't find a different idea, or any design pattern which can handle this issue.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set a JMS property with the value of your "MessageType" enum. `JMSType` is a built-in property that you can use for that or you can add your own property to every message (with a name like "MessageType")

On the client side, read the message and test the value of that property and convert it back to the enum in a switch statement then perform the casting of the message based on the object of the class associated with the message, Use only one topic, each client subscribing to the topic.

Instead of the switch statement, you can have one listener per message type based on a JMS selector, each one selecting only one value of the JMS property (ie MessageType). All depends of your use case of course (strict ordering etc.)

Comment: This is the proper way to route messages on the same queue with different types.

Answer (score 0):

You can use different topics/queues for different message categories.

You can also add properties to your message.

You can use a framework like spring that can do this for you, specially `MessageListenerAdapter`. Have a look at [spring jms](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/jms.html).

EDIT :

I can see some Design Pattern you can have a look at : `Chain of Responsability`, maybe `Observer` or `EventListener`.

The point here is that you have only one *handler*, that will handle all kinds of messages, read a property and then decide how to handle it. The solution may be to have many *handlers*, one by kind of message, and to find a way to route messages to the right handler.

`Chain of Responsability` can do the trick here : pass the message to the first handler of the chain, if it is concerned by the message then it can handle it, otherwise it will pass the message to the next handler, and so on.

Comment: The second option is like iv'e already added the 'MessageType' but still ended up in a huge switch case. But about the first option, I have 1 queue that the server is communicating with my client (each client has it's own clientId) and my problem is more at the message handling not at sending, and I need to use only jms and active mq (it's part of a project ;) )

Comment: Iv'e read about the Chain Of Responsibility, and it seems really interesting, btw if I need a topic sender/receiver for chat and queue sender/receiver for the rest, they still need to be under the same handler? or each one will have it's own "Communicator" ?

Comment: Depends on your structure, both are possible. You can even have two handler that share the same "communicator". But a good design principle is "separation of concern"...

Comment: I'll keep that in mind while refactoring my current code. Thank you very much!

Comment: You're welcome. Do not forget to accept the answer if it was usefull... ;)